# Tinymce 4 toolbar icons not appear

Tags: asp.net, tinymce-4

I have an asp.net project and I am using tinymce 4. It was working perfectly but totay my editors buttons suddenly disappeared. I searched for the solution from the internet but I could not find any solution.

the icons like on the picture. what should I do.
Regards...

[image]

```
<script src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinyMCE.init({
        forced_root_block: "",//remove p tags
        mode: "textareas",
        selector: ".tinymce",
        theme: "modern",
        height: 450,
        resize: false,
        statusbar: false,
        plugins: ["advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"],
        toolbar1: "styleselect | bold italic underline | pagebreak code preview | undo redo | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent ",
    });
</script>




 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_reading" runat="server" CssClass="tinymce"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: could you include some code of what you are currently using to produce your output?

Comment: this code has been working. Even thought I did not make any change the icons disappeared.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=6190) which looks like your issue, does not look promising :(

Comment: does it matter what browser you use? i.e. IE8, IE9, FF, Chrome, etc.

Comment: in the examples on the site they use a `textarea`. I don't know if it makes a difference, have you tried adding `TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5"` properties to your `asp:TextBox` to ensure it is rendered as a textarea?

Comment: I add text mode as multiline but nothing.

Comment: I do not use 25 editor. A am using only 2 editor

Comment: I solve the problem. My solution is, I got the icons class name with inspect element, I write new css class and write fontavasome's css properties. it is working with all browsers....

Comment: I am glad to hear, sorry I could not be of any more assistance. You can provide your own answers on this, which then may help users in the future :)

Comment: I am trying to put the css codes to answer but the editor does not accept the code format.

Comment: .mce-i-bold, 
.mce-i-italic, 
.mce-i-underline, 
.mce-i-forecolor, 
.mce-i-backcolor, 
.mce-i-code, 
.mce-i-preview, 
.mce-i-undo, 
.mce-i-redo, 
.mce-i-alignleft, 
.mce-i-aligncenter, 
.mce-i-alignright, 
.mce-i-alignjustify, 
.mce-i-bullist, 
.mce-i-numlist, 
.mce-i-outdent, 
.mce-i-indent
{
   display: inline-block;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

}


.mce-i-bold:before
{
    content: "\f032";
}


.mce-i-italic:before
{
    content: "\f033";
}

Comment: .mce-i-underline:before{content: "\f0cd";}
.mce-i-forecolor:before{content: "\f031";}
.mce-i-backcolor:before{content: "\f031";}
.mce-i-code:before{content: "\f120";}
.mce-i-preview:before{content: "\f06e";}
.mce-i-undo:before{content: "\f0e2";}
.mce-i-redo:before{content: "\f01e";}
.mce-i-alignleft:before{content: "\f036";}

Comment: mce-i-aligncenter:before{content: "\f037";}
.mce-i-alignright:before{content: "\f038";}
.mce-i-alignjustify:before{content: "\f039";}
.mce-i-bullist:before{content: "\f0ca";}
.mce-i-numlist:before{content: "\f0cb";}
.mce-i-outdent:before{content: "\f03b";}
.mce-i-indent:before{content: "\f03c";}

Comment: I have edited your question to help you format your answer, Hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not add my codes to answer so the following link is including the css codes.

I hope this will help if some one experience same issue in the future.

```
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
.mce-i-bold, 
.mce-i-italic, 
.mce-i-underline, 
.mce-i-forecolor, 
.mce-i-backcolor, 
.mce-i-code, 
.mce-i-preview, 
.mce-i-undo, 
.mce-i-redo, 
.mce-i-alignleft, 
.mce-i-aligncenter, 
.mce-i-alignright, 
.mce-i-alignjustify, 
.mce-i-bullist, 
.mce-i-numlist, 
.mce-i-outdent, 
.mce-i-indent,
.mce-i-newdocument,
.mce-i-print,
.mce-i-cut,
.mce-i-copy,
.mce-i-paste,
.mce-i-media,
.mce-i-image,
.mce-i-link,
.mce-i-charmap,
.mce-i-anchor,
.mce-i-selected,
.mce-i-strikethrough,
.mce-i-superscript,
.mce-i-subscript,
.mce-i-removeformat,
.mce-i-table,
.mce-i-close:before
{
display: inline-block;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

}


.mce-i-bold:before
{
    content: "\f032";
}


.mce-i-italic:before
{
    content: "\f033";
}


.mce-i-underline:before
{
    content: "\f0cd";
}

.mce-i-forecolor:before
{
    content: "\f031";
}

.mce-i-backcolor:before
{
    content: "\f031";
}



.mce-i-code:before
{
    content: "\f121";
}


.mce-i-preview:before
{
    content: "\f06e";
}


.mce-i-undo:before
{
    content: "\f0e2";
}


.mce-i-redo:before
{
    content: "\f01e";
}


.mce-i-alignleft:before
{
    content: "\f036";
}


.mce-i-aligncenter:before
{
    content: "\f037";
}


.mce-i-alignright:before
{
    content: "\f038";
}


.mce-i-alignjustify:before
{
    content: "\f039";
}

.mce-i-bullist:before
{
    content: "\f0ca";
}


.mce-i-numlist:before
{
    content: "\f0cb";
}


.mce-i-outdent:before
{
    content: "\f03b";
}

.mce-i-indent:before
{
    content: "\f03c";
}


.mce-i-newdocument:before
{
    content:"\f0f6" ;
}

.mce-i-print:before
{
    content: "\f02f";
}

.mce-i-cut:before
{
    content:"\f0c4" ;
}

.mce-i-copy:before
{
    content:"\f0c5" ;
}

.mce-i-paste:before
{
    content:"\f0ea" ;
}

.mce-i-media:before
{
    content: "\f008";
}

.mce-i-image:before
{
    content:"\f03e" ;
}

.mce-i-link:before
{
    content: "\f0c1";
}

.mce-i-charmap:before
{
    content:"\f195" ;
}

.mce-i-anchor:before
{
    content:"\f02e" ;
}

.mce-i-selected:before
{
    content:"\f00c" ;
}

.mce-i-strikethrough:before
{
    content:"\f0cc" ;
}

.mce-i-superscript:before
{
    content:"\f12b" ;
}

.mce-i-subscript:before
{
    content:"\f12c" ;
}

.mce-i-removeformat:before
{
    content:"\f12d" ;
}

.mce-i-table:before
{
    content:"\f0ce" ;
}


.mce-i-close:before
{
    content: "\f00d" ;
}


</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain anything helpful. What are you doing here? Where does this code go? And did this fix the problem?...

Comment: I did this and it fixed my problem... Even tought i dont understand how or why since i have included the CSS files of tinyMCE and those are already in it... But thank you anyways!